# Developers version of a phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have been programming for windows since about v2.1 and am interested in some apps for the phone now that it seems to be coming of age.

Search as I might, I cannot find a developer's unlocked version of a phone other than CDMA one and I can't use that as there is only AT&T and TMo available out here in the boonies.

Buying a dev's version for Android was simple as going to Moto's site and dropping one in the shopping cart.

If msoft are wondering why there are so few win-phone devs and/or, they might start looking at how hard or easy it is to get started. I have installed the SDK and the emulator is OK, but not something I would trust enough without testing it on my own phone.

Any helpful thoughts and suggestion on where to get a phone that it is not against the warranty to unlock?

Comment: Any win phone will work. They don't need a SIM card.  The Nokia 520 is super cheap. You can developer unlock one phone without joining the developer program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any windows phone as long as it supports the OS version (windows phone 8/8.1 is not supported in the older models) you're coding for. You don't need a developer version of a phone.

You need a developer's account though (should be 20/year now) and take a look at this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769508%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for registering your device. For older devices you need Zune software but it's not needed for windows phone 8 and up.

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to use a real device for testing, without wanting to buy a device, you could use the [Remote Device Access](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/remote-device-access) service

With it you can use a real device (located in Tampere/Finland) over the internet with your browser. Limitations include the lack of physically touching/rotating the device, and that calls/SMS are disabled both incoming & outgoing ones.